# How to only return in certain increments of days

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to return every 14 days starting from 12/31/2010 to 12/31/2011, but this statement doesn't seem to work

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Convert(varchar,Month(Time_Stamp)) + '/' +     
    Convert(varchar,DAY(Time_Stamp))
FROM Report
WHERE Time_Stamp LIKE '%2011%' AND     
Convert(varchar(20),DATEDIFF(D,'2010-12-31',Time_Stamp) / 14) NOT LIKE '%.%'
ORDER BY 1
```

This doesn't seem to work because it returns oddball dates...

```
1/1
1/10
1/11
```

When it should return every 14 days, like this...

```
1/14
1/28
2/11
```

and so on..

Anyone know a cleaner method, that actually works?

Comment: Try changing the 14 to 14.0 to stop the integer division.

Comment: @cjk yea that returns absolutely no rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the modulo value to offset the start date

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Convert(varchar,Month(Time_Stamp)) + '/' +     
    Convert(varchar,DAY(Time_Stamp))
FROM Report
WHERE
     Time_Stamp LIKE '%2011%'
     AND     
     DATEPART(dayofyear, Time_Stamp) % 14 = 0
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: I have no idea what a modulo is, but that did the trick, Thanks again!

Comment: @ZeeTee: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation A fancy name for basic maths "remainder" when you do division